# GNU Radio WSL Ubuntu 20.04 ImportError: libQt5Core

Tags: python, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

All,

After installing the Windows 10 Subsystem for Linux (WSL) and Ubuntu 20.04, I created a flowgraph that relied on QT.

The example I followed to install WSL and GNU is:
https://wiki.analog.com/resources/tools-software/linux-software/gnuradio

My Python version is 3.8.2 and my GRC version is 3.8.1.0

From the same terminal that I installed everthing, I finally launched GRC
`gnuradio-companion`

I built a flow graph and was greeted by an error when running it.
The error I receiver after building the flow graph is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jameshayek/GNURadio-Projects/FMReceiver.py", line 38, in <module>
    from gnuradio.qtgui import Range, RangeWidget
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gnuradio/qtgui/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    from .qtgui_swig import *
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gnuradio/qtgui/qtgui_swig.py", line 13, in <module>
    from . import _qtgui_swig
ImportError: libQt5Core.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I'd like to note,during the install, I did include
`sudo apt-get install qt5-default`

After going back to the terminal, I tried to `find` libQt5Core
`find /usr -name libQt5Core` but nothing returned. I am unsure why...

I included `gnuradio-dev` as well as `build-essential`

I also set my PYTHONPATH by finding it first using:

```
find /usr -name gnuradio | grep "packages"
```

Which returned `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gnuradio`

I then set the PYTHONPATH:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gnuradio
```

In the same terminal I was able to `echo $PYTHONPATH` to see:

```
:/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gnuradio
```

In a new terminal, the same command would yield nothing to return, so I modified the `~./bashrc` file to include the path stated above. All new terminals now spew out `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gnuradio`

Thinking this was an issue with the PATH I assumed the problem would have been resolved.
So, after closing out GRC and all Ubuntu terminals, I relaunched a new terminal to call GRC.

Same error. Nothing I did helped.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like [WSL's issue #3023](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/3023). Make sure you've `libqt5core5a` package installed on your system and then try applying the `strip` workaround as described in the issue.

```
sudo apt-get install libqt5core5a
sudo strip --remove-section=.note.ABI-tag /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
```

> After going back to the terminal, I tried to find libQt5Core find /usr -name libQt5Core but nothing returned.

In order to find the file you need to either use a regex or specify the full filename.

```
$ find /usr -name "libQt5Core.so*"
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5

$ find /usr -name libQt5Core.so.5
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
```

Comment: Thank you. I actually had `libqt5core5a` but neglected to document it. I would have never realized to use the `objdump` line or even use the `strip` command, so much obliged.